# Pandas import csv - Probl.m with a single quote

Tags: csv, pandas, quote

I am trying to read a csv file with `pandas` :

```
pd.read_csv(path, sep=";", quoting=3)
```

but I get an error :

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 8 fields in line 442069, saw 9
```

How can I read this file into a `pandas`' **`DataFrame`** ?

---

Edit after 1st comment : looking at the correct row :

```
$ more +442065 contacts.txt 
001-NM-001440;001-NM-368564;DIRECTEUR DE L'ETABLISSEMENT;DIRECTEUR DE L'ETABLISSEMENT;N;N;N;1
001-NPB-000649;001-NPB-440850; ;;N;N;N;0
001-NPB-000666;001-NPB-453937;DIRECTEUR DE L'ETABLISSEMENT;DIRECTEUR DE L'ETABLISSEMENT;N;N;N;0
001-NS-001217;001-CRM-469397;ASSISTANT(E);ASSISTANT(E);N;N;N;0
001-NS-001259;001-CRM-172012;ASSISTANT CHEF DE SECTEUR;;SECRETAIRE;N;N;N;0
001-MM-000288;001-MM-042968; ;;N;N;N;1
001-NYB-000005;286-INITOSM-33223; ;;N;N;N;0
001-NYB-000006;286-INITOSM-33230; ;;N;N;N;0
001-NYB-000011;001-NYB-312184;CONDUCTEUR DE TRAVAUX;CONDUCTEUR DE TRAVAUX;N;N;N;0
001-NYB-000011;001-NYB-1598768;CHEF DE CHANTIER;CHEF DE CHANTIER;N;N;N;0
001-NYB-000416;001-NYB-226960; ;;N;N;N;0
001-OLO-000171;286-INITOSM-33683;DIRECTEUR FINANCIER;DIRECTEUR FINANCIER;N;N;N;0
001-OLO-000192;001-OLO-033801;DIRECTEUR DE L'ETABLISSEMENT;DIRECTEUR DE L'ETABLISSEMENT;N;N;N;1
001-OLO-000259;286-INITOSM-33727;CONDUCTEUR DE TRAVAUX;CONDUCTEUR DE TRAVAUX;N;N;N;0
```

Comment: Are you sure the sample data you pasted is the error as it reads fine for me, is this line 442069?

Comment: very good point ! Let me check

Comment: I guess the faulty line is this one : 001-NS-001259;001-CRM-172012;ASSISTANT CHEF DE SECTEUR;;SECRETAIRE;N;N;N;0

Comment: Please edit updates into the question, also that line still works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A: Your pieces of data require sanity checking & some policy to detect + solve colliding cases

Sure, not an easy task, however Pandas have no trouble to import properly formatted orthogonal data. Get your inputs into a feasible state ( via a syntactic parser or a sanity pre-wrapping *suspicious* segments into "..." et al ) & **`pandas`** get 'em loaded into **`DataFrame`**.

```
Expected: 8-fields
Present:  1.  001-NS-001259;
          2.  001-CRM-172012;
          3.  ASSISTANT CHEF DE SECTEUR;
          4.  ;
          5.  SECRETAIRE;
          6.  N;
          7.  N;
          8.  N;
          9.  0
```